# Problems with background image position on Stellar.js

Tags: javascript, css, parallax

I'm using [stellar.js](https://github.com/markdalgleish/stellar.js) to add a parallax effect to a vertical scrolling website, but I'm having problems with the background positions. When I use the class "data-stellar-background-ratio" to add the parallax effect on a div I can't set the background position to right via CSS. All the background images just go to the left no matter what. I tried to use the position property plugin syntax available on the website, but it seems to break the parallax effect somehow.
Can anybody help me? 
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Use popular tags describing the technologies/languages or frameworks you are using. This will help others to find and answer your question.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue.

In your jquery.stellar.js file change the stellar function so that horizontal scrolling is set to false (its set to true as default).

```
$.stellar({
horizontalScrolling:false
// rest of function
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try changing `scrollProperty` to `transform`, like:

```
scrollProperty: 'transform'
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and already had `horizontalScrolling:false`. Adding `scrollProperty: 'transform'` resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue I tried adding

```
scrollProperty and horizontalScrolling
```

Though this resulted in my background not being loaded.

Removing both properties and running Stellar like..

```
$.stellar({}) instead of $.stellar()
```

(like on the Stellar site)

Parallax is working like a charm.