# How to center parallax backgrounds with stellar.js when scaling

Tags: javascript, html, css, stellar.js

I'm experiencing some issues with parallax background images.

I'm working with [this template](https://freehtml5.co/demos/nuptial/). As you can see, in the home page there are 2 divs exploiting `stellar.js` (i.e., `.fh5co-cover` and `#fh5co-started` ). All seems fine with a computer resolution but if I try to visualize the website with a Phone resolution (e.g., simulating the iPhone7 Plus rendering through Chrome) the background image in `.fh5co-cover` is not centered. Moreover the background image in `#fh5co-started` displays grey borders when you scroll the page.

Is there a way for centering background images and for avoiding those annoying grey borders at small resolutions?

Comment: possible duplicate of this; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930504/css-background-image-centered-with-stellar-js

Comment: Hi @floatingpurr, please include a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: @Curt is not a duplicated. the link you gave him is an static background image, his is a parallax background image

Comment: When I checked out the template link I also saw the parallax images shifted to the left, As @markdalgleish mentions in his answer, try to disable horizontal parallax and see if that fixes your centering issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/15939327/2981242

Comment: Hi @TylerH, in the link of my question you can see the problem in action

Comment: Hello @Curt, thanks for your observation. I think this is not the duplicate. Besides, I've already tried the solution you've mentioned before posting.

Comment: @floatingpurr You need to include a [mcve] in the question itself. Your question loses its value when the link dies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the background position x to 50%:

`background-position-x: 50%;`

In here:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
.fh5co-cover {
    heifght: inherit;
    padding: 3em 0;
    background-position-x: 50% !important;
}
```

PD: `important!` because the position is being changed in js by whatever plugin you are using.

About the gray border,  couldn't find it so i guess was just a bug on your browser

Comment: Great! Worked like a charm! PS: while you scroll, you can see the grey border of the background in the `<div id="fh5co-started">`, indicatively under the button _"I am attending"_